# Inserting swiffy converted html5 into webpage

Tags: iframe

I converted swf files from my static html website into html5 with swiffy. But I don't know how to insert them in webpage so that they look exactly like swf files. I used iframe but it makes block of inserted html5 file instead of merging it with background color.

Please check original website
www.coldhousellc.com

I am currently trying on its white logo.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code in the question? Thanks

Comment: Following is the code i am trying to use instead of <object> element already used in the website: <iframe src="../animations/could_house_logo.htm" height="125" width="189" style="background-color:transparent; border:hidden;"></iframe>

Comment: Original Code already in website:
<object id="FlashID2" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="282" height="180">
<param name="movie" value="../animations/contact_us_banner.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
 <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../animations/contact_us_banner.swf" width="282" height="180">
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
</object>